# Can't make multiline text on d3 pie chart

Tags: angular, d3.js, svg, multiline

I'm having a problem with multiline text and have no clue and I need your help, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/se2fdzgz/).

i have very limited space for this pie chart,
but the titles of items are long, the problem is no matter what i tried i couldnt break to multiline,
i tried to limit the width of text but it didnt work, i think canvas not accepting css properties?

complete code is in fiddle

problem code here:

```
var donuts = d3.selectAll("#" + el + ' .donut');

donuts.append('text')
        .attr('class', 'center-txt value')
        .style('font-size', '16px')
        .style('fill','rgba(255,255,255,0.8)')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');

donuts.append('text')
        .append('tspan')
        .attr('class', 'center-txt type')
        .attr('y', chart_r * 0.20)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .style('font-size', '22px')
        .style('fill','rgba(255,255,255,0.8)')
        .text(function(d, i) {
            return d.type;
        });
donuts.append('text')
        .append('tspan')
        .attr('class', 'center-txt percentage')
        .attr('y', chart_r * 0.20)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .style('font-size', '18px')
        .style('fill','rgba(255,255,255,0.8)')
        .text('');
```

}

thank you

Comment: Why did you put "canvas" in the title and a `canvas` tag? That's an SVG, not a canvas.

Comment: yes sorry my bad, elements are created same way i was confused, thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different approaches to solve your problem. One of them is using Mike Bostock's function [wrap](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321), to break your text elements.

Here is an example setting the limit to 120px:

```
thisDonut.select('.percentage')
    .attr("dy", 0)
    .text(function(donut_d) {
        return d.data.cat
    }).call(wrap, 120);
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zkLyt5fm/